# Sub select SQL query using where and groupby

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

When I try below code in SQL Server,

```
SELECT       
dbo.Category.CatNo as Category, 
dbo.Category.Categaory as Name, 
(select SUM(dbo.SALES.SELLINC) where (dbo.SALES.DATE BETWEEN '2016-07-17' AND '2016-07-23')) AS ActualSales, 
(select SUM(dbo.SALES.SELLINC) where (dbo.SALES.DATE BETWEEN '2015-07-19' AND '2015-07-25')) AS LastYrVariance,
(select SUM(dbo.SALES.SELLINC) where (dbo.SALES.DATE BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-09-05')) AS YrToDateActual,
(select SUM(dbo.SALES.SELLINC) where (dbo.SALES.DATE BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-09-05')) AS LastYrToDateActual  
FROM dbo.Category INNER JOIN
     dbo.Dissection ON dbo.Category.CatNo = dbo.Dissection.CatNo INNER JOIN
     dbo.Division ON dbo.Dissection.DivNo = dbo.Division.ID INNER JOIN
     dbo.Departments ON dbo.Dissection.DeptNo = dbo.Departments.DeptID INNER JOIN
     dbo.SALES ON dbo.Dissection.DissNo = dbo.SALES.CODE
WHERE (dbo.SALES.BRN = 1) 
GROUP BY dbo.Category.CatNo, dbo.Category.Categaory
ORDER BY dbo.Category.CatNo
```

I get below error message,

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>       Column 'dbo.Category.CatNo' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY
>   clause.

Any help please?

Comment: May be you forgot to select(highlight) last two lines when press "execute" ?

Comment: You have a spelling mistake for `Categaory` in the `GROUP BY` clause.  That shouldn't be the cause of that particular error, but still...

Comment: @PhillipXT - Even in the Select list it is the same spelling `..dbo.Category.Categaory as Name..`

Comment: Yeah, too early in the morning... I was looking at the wrong spot...

Comment: The subqueries have a select clause, with a Sum() function which attempts to Sum the values from a column of a table that is not mentioned in the Subquery.  (The subqueries have no FROM clause).  These subqueries should not be subqueries, they just need to be Sum() expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cant find a reason to generate that error in your query. Between you can simply those `sub-queries` by using `CASE` statements

```
SELECT dbo.category.catno     AS Category, 
       dbo.category.categaory AS NAME, 
       Sum(CASE WHEN dbo.sales.date BETWEEN '2016-07-17' AND '2016-07-23' THEN dbo.sales.sellinc END) AS ActualSales, 
       Sum(CASE WHEN dbo.sales.date BETWEEN '2015-07-19' AND '2015-07-25' THEN dbo.sales.sellinc END) AS LastYrVariance, 
       Sum(CASE WHEN dbo.sales.date BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-09-05' THEN dbo.sales.sellinc END) AS YrToDateActual, 
       Sum(CASE WHEN dbo.sales.date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-09-05' THEN dbo.sales.sellinc END) AS LastYrToDateActual 
FROM   dbo.category 
       INNER JOIN dbo.dissection 
               ON dbo.category.catno = dbo.dissection.catno 
       INNER JOIN dbo.division 
               ON dbo.dissection.divno = dbo.division.id 
       INNER JOIN dbo.departments 
               ON dbo.dissection.deptno = dbo.departments.deptid 
       INNER JOIN dbo.sales 
               ON dbo.dissection.dissno = dbo.sales.code 
WHERE  ( dbo.sales.brn = 1 ) 
GROUP  BY dbo.category.catno, 
          dbo.category.categaory 
ORDER  BY dbo.category.catno
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. Could you please help me with another question? for the below query ------Sum(CASE WHEN dbo.sales.date BETWEEN '2016-07-17' AND '2016-07-23' THEN dbo.sales.sellinc END) AS ActualSales---- instead of hard coding the date. I would like to pick current date from machine and compare----Sum(CASE WHEN dbo.sales.date BETWEEN 'previous week (31 week 2016)' AND 'Last year same week (31 week 2015)' THEN dbo.sales.sellinc END) AS ActualSales----

Answer (score 1):

The subqueries have a select clause, with a Sum() function which attempts to Sum the values from a column of a table that is not mentioned in the Subquery. (The subqueries have no FROM clause). These subqueries should not be subqueries, they just need to be Sum() expressions.
And you should check into using aliases to simplify your SQL scripts.

```
SELECT c.CatNo Category, c.Categaory Name, 
     sum(case when s.Date between '2016-07-17' and '2016-07-23' 
           then s.SELLINC else 0 end) ActualSales,
     sum(case when s.Date between '2015-07-25' and '2015-07-19'
           then s.SELLINC else 0 end) LastYrVariance,
     sum(case when s.Date between '2016-01-01' and '2016-09-05' 
           then s.SELLINC else 0 end) YrToDateActual,
     sum(case when s.Date between '2015-01-01' AND '2015-09-05'
           then s.SELLINC else 0 end) LastYrToDateActual 
FROM dbo.Category c
      join dbo.Dissection d on d.CatNo = c.CatNo 
      join dbo.Division v on v.Id = d.DivNo 
      join dbo.Departments p on p.DeptID = d.DeptNo 
      join dbo.SALES s on s.code = d.DissNo 
WHERE s.BRN = 1 
GROUP BY c.CatNo, c.Categaory
ORDER BY c.CatNo
```

to generate date range dynamically, as requested in comment, use datediff and dateAdd functions: I'm not sure what you meant by **previous week (31 week 2016)**  or **Last year same week (31 week 2015)**, so if this is not right, you can modify to correct.

```
SELECT c.CatNo Category, c.Categaory Name, 
     sum(case when s.Date between 
           dateAdd(week, datediff(week, 0, getdate())-52, 0) 
       and dateAdd(week, datediff(week, 0, getdate()), 0) 
           then s.SELLINC else 0 end) ActualSales,
     sum(case when s.Date between '2015-07-25' and '2015-07-19'
           then s.SELLINC else 0 end) LastYrVariance,
     sum(case when s.Date between '2016-01-01' and '2016-09-05' 
           then s.SELLINC else 0 end) YrToDateActual,
     sum(case when s.Date between '2015-01-01' AND '2015-09-05'
           then s.SELLINC else 0 end) LastYrToDateActual 
FROM dbo.Category c
      join dbo.Dissection d on d.CatNo = c.CatNo 
      join dbo.Division v on v.Id = d.DivNo 
      join dbo.Departments p on p.DeptID = d.DeptNo 
      join dbo.SALES s on s.code = d.DissNo 
WHERE s.BRN = 1 
GROUP BY c.CatNo, c.Categaory
ORDER BY c.CatNo
```

Comment: For the below query 

    `Sum(CASE WHEN dbo.sales.date BETWEEN '2016-07-17' AND '2016-07-23' THEN dbo.sales.sellinc END) AS ActualSales`

Instead of hard coding the date. I would like to pick current date from machine and compare

    `Sum(CASE WHEN dbo.sales.date BETWEEN '**previous week (31 week 2016)**' AND '**Last year same week (31 week 2015)**' THEN dbo.sales.sellinc END) AS ActualSales`

Week start from Sunday and ends Saturday. Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

can you try with the below query.

```
 SELECT   Category.CatNo as Category, Category.Categaory as Name, 
(select SUM(SALES.SELLINC) where (SALES.DATE BETWEEN '2016-07-17' AND '2016-07-23')) AS ActualSales, 
(select SUM(SALES.SELLINC) where (SALES.DATE BETWEEN '2015-07-19' AND '2015-07-25')) AS LastYrVariance,
(select SUM(SALES.SELLINC) where (SALES.DATE BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-09-05')) AS YrToDateActual,
(select SUM(SALES.SELLINC) where (SALES.DATE BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-09-05')) AS LastYrToDateActual  
FROM            dbo.Category INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Dissection ON Category.CatNo = Dissection.CatNo INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Division ON Dissection.DivNo = Division.ID INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Departments ON Dissection.DeptNo = Departments.DeptID INNER JOIN
                         dbo.SALES ON Dissection.DissNo = SALES.CODE
WHERE        (SALES.BRN = 1) 

GROUP BY Category.CatNo, Category.Categaory
ORDER BY Category.CatNo
```